# How to format output MySQL date in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel, time

I have several fields in a form with dates and times `('dd-mm-yyyy', 'hh:mm')`.

When I want to save the form I use my own function to convert it for MySQL `('yyyy-mm-dd', 'H:i:s')` via date() which I added to save() in Laravel `Model` Class.

But where is single place where I can put the same function to format output (SELECT queries)? 
There is no single function in Laravel for data output. `find()`, `findOrNew()`, `findOrFail()`, ... - there are in different classes so I cant use single place to add the formatting function.

Is there any proper place to put formatting function?

Comment: I dont want to do it in controller so I want to find a proper place in Models :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel Date Mutator. Just put the following method in your Eloquent Model:

Suppose your have a table user in your database with expireDate column. then define this field in your model.

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $dates = ['expireDate'];

}
```

Just Replace FirstName with your database column name.
Then you can use laravel Carbon class to format your result.

```
$user = User::find(1);
return $user->expireDate->format('d-m-Y');
```

For more reference please read the http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#date-mutators

Comment: I've been using this approach myself and it's very convenient.  It has the advantage that you can't forget about it - once you've set the $dates attribute on the Model, those attributes of the model will ALWAYS be Carbon dates.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to `AppServiceProvider@register`:

```
Carbon::setToStringFormat('d/m/y');
```

Now you can just echo `$model->created_at` and everything’s formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In App directory, create a new directory. Let call it "`libraries`",
then create a php file "CustomFunction.php" or whatever, this has to be a class as well, then put your function in this class.

So you have

```
class CustomFunction{

    static function dateFormat(){

  }
}
```

in `App/libraries`/

```
Then in App/start/global.php
```

Iside classloader on line 14, as below, add the path to your new folder:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/libraries'

));
```

Then in your composer.json file, add:
"`app/libraries`" to "`autoload`" array.

Then in your view you can easily do this:

```
{{ CustomFunction::dateFormat() }}
```